# CSS display block and floated elements (css mastery) Can this be done?

Tags: css

So I'm developing a mobile micro site and that said, I want the links on the page, to behave
like ios links/tabs do, that when you click on them, the whole width of the button is active and changes color to display a click/finger over state etc..plus the WHOLE width of that div behaves like a button so that either on a small phone or a tablet, as long as I don't specify a width, that its active state goes from left to right ALL THE WAY as a "block"

To that effect for example, if I have a regular text link. like this:

```
<div class="mainBtns"><a href="gallery.php">Portfolio</a></div>
```

id give it this CSS so that on mouseover/click with finget etc, that it behaves like an ios button/tab.

```
CSS:

        .mainBtns a{
            display:block;

        }

    .mainBtns a:hover{
        background-color:#d8d3cb;   

    }
```

Now that said. This is the problem im trying to solve.

I have a parent Div called **thumbItemW** (the content wrapper);
and two child items called **galThumb** and **galThumbtxt**

The content block looks like this:

```
<div class="thumbItemW ">
    <div class="galThumb">
        <a href="gallery-highrise.php" alt=""><img src="images/thumbs/highrise.jpeg" alt="High rise Gallery" />
        </a>
    </div> **//this is the gallery thumb floated left**

<div class="galThumbTxt"> 
    <a href="gallery-highrise.php" alt="">HIGH RISE CONTEMPORARY</a>
</div>**//this is the gallery thumb text floated right**
    <div class="clearEm"> </div>//clear the float
</div> <!-- thumbItemW ender -->
```

What I want to do is that, when the user finger clicks the parent div, that the background color changes like in the example above with `"mainBtns / mainBtns a:hover"`

Problem is that, unlike the first example with mainBtns, since this one has child items, if I do something like:

```
pseudo CSS:

.thumbItemW  a:hover{
    display:block;  
}
```

or something like this, this doesn't work the way id want it, since the elements are floats inside this parent div.

What I'm wanting to do is make the parent div **.thumbItemW** be like a display block so that when the user clicks, that they can click ANYwhere along that divs width and still activate the button as oppose to clicking RIGHT ontop of the button or text.

Can this be achieved the way I have it? Can this be achieved with CSS alone WITHOUT javascript/jquery?

Hope it's not too confusing.

Comment: Your situation is a bit hard to understand since you are describing a visual layout problem. If you can add an image (wireframe or mockup) of what you are after that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

why wouldn't you just specify width and height on the a element?

Comment: because i need it to be flexible for multiple widths. If i specify a width/height, then itll be "fixed" essentially.

Comment: Why not write separate rules for different a's as children of different divs and use percentages? They won't be wider than the containing divs.

Comment: If you have a floated element, then you must specify a width with either a percentage or an absolute value or else the default is that it's width will only be as large as it's contents.

Comment: lol, i understand what yall are saying but, what i mean is, The parent Divs width is equal to its inner contents, that said, since i have one inner item floated left and the other right, then that covers the width portion. The problem im having is targeting the parent div on hover so i can apply a background color for example to illustrate an active button area. Both inner items are items wrapped in links but....as far as i know i cant wrap a div in a link can i? like this isnt good is it --> " <a href="#"><div>content</div></a> "

Comment: well the hover event does bubble up to the parent, so you should be able to use the :hover pseudoclass on the parent.

Comment: so something like #parentDiv :hover{ something here } ??

Comment: I forgot to add, don't use a space.  #myContainer:hover not #myContainer :hover.  Also if you haven't declared a doctype it won't work in IE.

Comment: However, if you want to make the whole element act like an anchor tag, you're still going to need to make the anchor element cover the whole  parent.  Is that what you're trying to do?